# Want to plot a function between [a,b] and on the same plot shade the area under [c,d] where c and d lie between a and b

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a function using ggplot, which I can do. For example y = x. I plot between -1 and 4. Works great. On the same graph I now want to shade the area under the curve between 1 and 3. I cannot get it to work, nor can I find any documentation. Can someone help me?

Skeleton code that I'm trying:

```
eq<-function(x){(x)}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-1,4)),aes(x)) + 
stat_function(fun=eq,geom="line",color="red") + 
stat_function(fun=eq,geom="area",fill="blue")
```

I tried all different permutations. If there was a way to limit the second stat_function to a different domain it might work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `stat_function` is working over the full range of data, rather than with the particular values supplied. One option is to generate the data you want to plot first, then pass it to a specific `geom_*`. However, if you really want to stay with `stat_function`, you may need to do a bit more work around. One approach would be to create two functions, one of which limits the outputs to the range you want.

```
eq<-function(x){(x)}
eqB<-function(x){ifelse(x < 3 & x > 0, x, NA)}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-1,4)),aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq,geom="line",color="red") + 
  stat_function(fun=eqB,geom="area",fill="blue")
```

A more robust solution is to create a single function that accepts range limits, then pass those in using `args`:

```
eqC <- function(x,upr = max(x), lwr = min(x)){
  ifelse(x <= upr & x >= lwr, x, NA)
}

ggplot(data.frame(x=c(-1,4)),aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eqC,geom="line",color="red") + 
  stat_function(fun=eqC,geom="area",fill="blue"
                , args = list(upr = 3, lwr = 0))
```

Both of these generate a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Mark, I guessed that stat_function was working over the full range of data for both plots, but I could not come up with a way around it. What you created was excellent and does exactly what I wanted. I tried it against a variety of functions, including the standard normal curve, and it works great. Thank you very much! Tony