# plot function in defined interval

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to define the boundaries where the function will be ploted in `ggplot2` figure 
Ex

```
f <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 10)), aes(x))
test <- function(x) {x ^ 2 + x + 20}
f + stat_function(fun = test)
```

Is this a way to plot the `test` function in the interval ex `c(2, 5)`

Comment: `+ xlim(c(2, 5))`?

Comment: but it just restricts the figure. I want to keep figure in the interval `c(0, 10)` and plot the line just in the interval `c(2, 5)`

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `stat_function()` but there are a lot of other workarounds in ggplot2 using `geom`s. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002518/want-to-plot-a-function-between-a-b-and-on-the-same-plot-shade-the-area-under

Comment: `f + geom_blank() + stat_function(fun = test, xlim = c(2, 5))`

Comment: Ok! it works nice! Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set x limits within `stat_function` and use `geom_blank` to get the x limits corresponding to the data:

```
f + geom_blank() + stat_function(fun = test, xlim = c(2, 5))
```